# Write "Code Golf" without using any letters

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

## Goal

Your goal is to write "Code Golf" without using any letters [A-Z, a-z], even in your source code. It can't use of the following special characters either (!, _, <, (, ), ., {, }, ', and >).

## Bonus / Scoring

- If the code backwards also writes "Code Golf", you get -10.

Good luck! 
Standard loopholes disallowed.
Mine also isn't a duplicate, because it also has character restrictions.

Comment: You wouldn't know this as a new user, but challenges of the form "Print X without using characters Y" have been poorly received in general. It seems like every new user comes in thinking it's a new and clever idea, which means they've been way overdone at this point. A lot of the answers use the same bag of tricks. Doing a simple task with limited tools often leads to less interesting solutions than a difficult task with a large array of tools. Try doing some challenges yourself to get a sense of what the community is into.

Comment: Also, having username-dependence is a bad idea. It means users whose names is shorter or longer or more compressible have an unfair advantage. It's not fun to be unable to use a method because your username doesn't allow it.

Comment: Ok - i'll fix it up a little more.

Comment: Maybe too restrictive??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 25

```
"¡ÍÂÃ~¥ÍÊÄ"94"`[]":^"-"+~
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%C2%A1%C3%8D%C3%82%C3%83~%C2%A5%C3%8D%C3%8A%C3%84%2294%22%60%5B%5D%22%3A%5E%22-%22%2B~)

**Explanation:**

"¡ÍÂÃ~¥ÍÊÄ" is "Code Golf" with each character (code point) incremented by 94.

```
"¡ÍÂÃ~¥ÍÊÄ"94    push that string and 94
"`[]":^          xor the characters '`', '[' and ']', obtaining 'f'
"-"+             concatenate with "-", resulting in "f-"
~                evaluate "f-", which subtracts 94 from each character
```

Comment: That's really clever. I had the string, but I couldn't figure out how to produce the `f`...

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I used another method first (you can see it in the edit history)

Answer (score 5):

## HTML, 46 bytes

```
&#67;&#111;&#100;&#101; &#71;&#111;&#108;&#102;
```

This prints / outputs:

Code Golf

Answer (score 4):

## Whitespace, 146 characters

I have included `S`pace, `T`ab, and `L`ine feed indicators.

```
S S S T S S S S T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S S S T T   S S T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S S S T T   S S T   S T L
T   L
S S S S S S S S T   S S S S S L
T   L
S S S S S S S T S S S T T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S S T   T   S L
T   L
S S L
L
L
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/MZQAlN)

**Explanation:**

- `S S` pushes a number to the stack
- `S T S S S S T   T   L` is the number 67 in binary ending with a line
- `T   L
  S S` outputs the top of the stack
- This process repeats for each letter
- Three linefeeds at the end terminates the program

Note that this does not end with a linefeed, so the command prompt will appear directly after the output.  There is also some easy golfing by manipulating the stack and/or creating the numbers more efficiently, but it's past my bedtime...

**Edit:**  I am unable to sleep and have been inspired by vihan1086's HTML answer.  I don't see a requirement that the backwards-forwards running be in one language, so here is an **WHITESPACE + LMTH** answer that runs forwards and backwards:

```
;201#&;801#&;111#&;17#&;23#&;101#&;001#&;111#&;76#&
```

This scores 146 + 50 - 10 = 186

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 27 bytes

```
0000000: 5b 31 32 33 20 31 32 36 20 31 32 35 5d 2b 7e  [123 126 125]+~
000000f: 22 bc 90 9b 9a df b8 90 93 99 22 25           "........."%
```

The above is a reversible xxd dump.

The only ASCII characters the code uses are `[123 65]+~"%`.

#### Proof of work

```
$ LANG=en_US
$ xxd -ps -r > codegolf.gs <<< 5b31323320313236203132355d2b7e22bc909b9adfb89093992225
$ wc -c codegolf.gs
27 codegolf.gs
$ golfscript codegolf.gs 
Code Golf
```

#### How it works

- Lacking input, GolfScript initially has an empty string on the stack.
- The array `[123 126 125]` contains the character codes of `{`, `~` and `}`.
- `+` concatenates. Since strings take priority over arrays, this pushes `"{~}"`.
- `~` evaluates that string, pushing the block `{~}`.
- The string of non-ASCII characters contains the logical NOTs of the character code of the string **Code Golf**.
- `%` maps the pushed block over the string. `~` is logical NOT, which is involutive, so this pushes the character codes of **Code Golf**.
- Finally, GolfScript prints the string on the stack.